# unable to install packages on 3.6.3

Tags: r, package

Every time I try to install any packages in R, I get an error

> [image]

I have tried a lot of things before I posted my question, like unchecking the box for secure HTTP.

> [image]

I have also tried this solution that was posted before:

> [image]

I have been stuck trying to solve that issue for three days, I have tried a lot of solutions that have been posted before and none of them worked for me.

Comment: indeed, http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES is "Not Found"

Comment: If you're set on R 3.6, the packages will come from [here](https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/). To use this URL, when calling `install.packages`, add the argument `contriburl = "https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/"`

Answer (score 1):

Per your commented request, here's my comment as an answer. I'm glad it worked for you!

If you're set on R 3.6, the packages will come from [here](https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/). To use this URL, when calling `install.packages`, add the argument

```
contriburl = "https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/"
```